# Which modal verbs mean bigger or less probability of something to happen?

Tags: modal-verbs, shall-will

I would like to know a degree of probability wich modal verbs indicate when used. If there is any probability scale for these verbs from the lowest probability to highest. I am also interested in how repetitive actions are related to the usage of the modal verbs.

Here are some examples of sentences that imply probability and repetitive actions but I am not sure about a degree of probability

> **1** It won't start - I think the battery's flat.
>
> **2** I asked him to park it somewhere else, but he wouldn't move it.
>
> **3** I wish  he would turn it down.
>
> **4** We can watch the match on the balcony if you'll just help me take it out there.
>
> **5** It would keep her amused on long car journeys - but we insisted she have the sound off.
>
> **6** He'll play with it all morning, his eyes glued to the tiny screen.
>
> **7** That'll be Mike. Don't answer it.
>
> **8** They'll have got there by now. Give it to me  - I know their number.
>
> **9** He will keep forgetting to turn it off. It gets so hot in the kitchen!
>
> **10** It would go wrong now, wouldn't it! Just as I put the meat in to roast.
>
> **11** There's no more room in it. Where shall I put the chicken?
>
> **12** Shall I defrost it now or when we come back?
>
> **13** I'll set it up for you if you like. It's the same as the one I use at work.
>
> **14** Shall I defrost it now or when we come back?
>
> **15** That would/will be my wife.

I would also like to see some examples with probabilities of could, might, may and other modal verbs.

Comment: There's no probability involved in *"I asked him to park it somewhere else, but he wouldn't move it."* We know with 100% certainty that he refused. Neither for *"It would keep her amused on long car journeys - but we insisted she have the sound off."* Nor for *"There's no more room in it. Where shall I put the chicken?"* Nor *"It would go wrong now, wouldn't it! Just as I put the meat in to roast."*

Comment: Modal verbs are not on a strength scale. There are several scales, and multiple ambiguities. Only epistemic senses of modals deal with (perceived) probability; deontic modal senses like the _wouldn't_ in (2), deal with (perceived) social or personal necessity and permission.

Comment: @PeterShor 100% Probability is still some Probability. And I believe "It would would keep her amused..." is not 100%. Probability is very high because of our previous experience. At least that my teacher said but I am unable to consult with him now.

Comment: In this sentence, *It would keep her amused* is a habitual past tense, nearly synonymous with *It used to keep her amused on long journeys*.  Maybe she's gotten older since then, and it wouldn't entertain her any more, maybe not. But the sentence itself doesn't say one way or the other.

Comment: Voting to close as 'Opinion based'.  But Q. is also unclear what is being asked.  Op asks about "degree of probability", and different people may interpret these expressions with differing degrees of probability. Q. is also also unclear, because many of expressions do not involve probability: e.g. items 12 & 14 say "Shall I defrost it now or when we come back?" - that is a straight question, with no reference to probability; item 7 "That'll be Mike. Don't answer it." is a straight statement, & probability does come into it.

Comment: @TrevorD "That'll be Mike. Don't answer it." Imagine someone is calling us on the phone. But we can see who is it. So in this context, this sentence is just an assumption. He can't be sure for 100% that it is Mike.

Comment: You have contradicted yourself! First: "we can see who is it." sounds like a certainty - if "you can see who it is" there is clearly NO ASSUMPTION! Your last two sentences contradict your previous sentence. If you "can see who is it." - then it is NOT "just an assumption".  But if you are not "sure for 100% that it is Mike", then your statement "we **can** see who is it." is NOT TRUE - you can only see who you **think** it **probably** is.

Comment: @TrevorD Sorry. That was a misspell. It was "can't".